# Format Datetime in Business Objects

Tags: datetime, business-intelligence

So I know I can use =FormatDate(MyDate ,"mm/dd/yy") to turn a date into a string.  I am then trying to add on a time:

```
=FormatDate(AdminDate ,"mm/dd/yy") + MyTime
```

Which works, however, I need to format this back to a datetime field (as I need to compare against a preexisting datetime field).  I try using Todate(), but the documentation is very light, and provides very little on what is acceptable in  the formatting of the date area, and nothing in the way of time!

I have attempted:

```
=ToDate(FormatDate(MyDate ,"mm/dd/yy HH:mm:ss") + MyTime ,"mm/dd/yy HH:mm:ss")
```

but this will only work when there is no time (and it just nulls out the time)  and any row with a time will return a #ERROR

Anyone have an insight on formatting datetimes?

Thanks

Comment: Business Intelligence, desktop edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to use the FormatDate command to output date and time components together in 12 hour format is:

```
=FormatDate(AdminDate; "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a")
```

and in 24 hour format is:

```
=FormatDate(AdminDate; "MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss")
```

Note MM is used in months and mm in minutes.